# Async Python - How to make a class __init__ run async functions within the class __init__

Tags: python, python-asyncio, init

Let's say I have this:

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        await self.TestPrint()

    async def TestPrint(self):
        print(self.number)
```

As you can see this won't work since `__init__` is not `async` and I cannot call `await` for the function.

I want to be able to run `TestPrint` within `__init__` **assuming I want to maintain this function async**.

I also want this to have nothing to do with anything else other than the class (other function, other classes, main, etc.).

Comment: I don't think you can (or should) do this. An asynchronous class method that creates the object and *then* calls the `TestPrint` method before returning it sounds more appropriate. `__init__` is for *initializing* the object, not for arbitrary code you want to run after initializing it.

Comment: this is almost-certainly an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
 .. what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

Like [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) mentioned in the comments:

> An asynchronous class method that creates the object and then calls the `TestPrint` method before returning it sounds more appropriate.

This is the preferred way above all else and why a lot of there are a lot of functions that initialize internal asyncio classes rather than you directly instantiating them.

That said, if you wish to have this close to the class you can use a [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) which can be async. Your code would look like this:

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    async def TestPrint(self):
            print(self.number)

    @classmethod
    async def with_print(cls, number):
        self = cls(number)
        await self.TestPrint()
        return self
```

```py
async def main():
    t = await Test.with_print(123)
    # 't' is now your Test instance.
    ...
```